# What does the AHRS do in the Garmin 175 series?

Tags: flight-instruments, gyroscopic-instruments, gps175

What function does the [AHRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system) perform in the Garmin 175 series? And how long should it take to perform the initialization of the AHRS component in the initial system configuration process?

[image: AHRS Calibrate screen]

I am just installing a Garmin GPS 175, and everything seems to be working except that the AHRS *Calibrate* process in the configuration never seems to complete. I have tried it several times, once for about twenty minutes, and it never completes or provides any error messages, and the only way to terminate it is to power off the unit.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, [take a look at the manual for the unit](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-02488-01_b.pdf)

> AHRS units have a magnetometer interface for determining magnetic heading.

The data may also be sent to any connected device like an iPad running foreflight.

[image]
([Source](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-02488-01_b.pdf))

Comment: Duh!  Oh yeah, just read the manual, why didn't ....     - I  *did* read the users manual, *and* the installation manual, and the ARINC-429 interface specifications, and none of them answer my question. Which puts your answer in good company I suppose.